# How to use dynamic schema in Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have one function dbo.test. Please find the function below:

```
Alter Function dbo.Test  
(  

)  
returns int  
As  
Begin  
Declare  @a int  
Select top 1 @a = Id from CustomFieldMaster 
return @a  
End
```

I am executeing the above function in my Database **Test**. The interesting thing is this that this database has schema **Test** not default **dbo** means the tables are like **Test.CustomFieldMaster**.

When I call my above function inside **Test** db, it gives me below error:

*Invalid object name 'CustomFieldMaster'*

I know the above function give me this erorr because it is trying to find **dbo.CustomFieldMaster** table instead of **Test.CustomFieldMaster**.

But I can't use Test schema as I have many databases with different schemas, so in future if I design a SP with many tables and want to execute that SP in every db than I have to manually change the schema name before executing that SP for every DB.

I want some keyword that dynamically picks the defauly schema of the current login user or current user as my schema name is same as User Name.

**UPDATE:**

```
Select Current_User
```

The above will give me the user name, but I don't want dynamic queries.

Any suggestions please.

**ANY QUICK HELP**

Comment: You will need dynamic SQL to specify schema name

Comment: @Szymon: Can you please explain your comment briefly

Comment: My answer didn't makes sense as I forgot you couldn't use dynamic SQL in function. But anyway, you won't be able to set the schema for the query, you have to specify it in the query.

Comment: Yeah No Prob, but that's what I don't want. As I already mentioned in my question that I have many databases with diff schema names so in that case I have to change manually and that is not feasable.

Comment: Use dynamic SQL to create the function.

Comment: Create your functions and SPs in the same schema as the tables i.e. 'Test'

Answer (score 0):

As we can't use dynamic sql in functions alternatively you can create a stored procedure as below. But this assumes that there is only one table named CustomFieldMaster in entire database with different schema name.

```
create proc dbo.TestProc
@a int  output
As  
Begin  

--
DECLARE @tableName nvarchar(100);
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

--Get full qualified tablename
select @tableName = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id('CustomFieldMaster')))
                     + N'.' 
                     + QUOTENAME('CustomFieldMaster')
FROM master.sys.objects;


SET @SQLString =
    N'SELECT top 1 @aOut = Id from '+ @tableName;


SET @ParmDefinition = N'@aOut int OUTPUT';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @aOut = @a OUTPUT;

--Select top 1 @a = Id from @tableName
select @a

End
Go
```

and then execute it as:

```
declare @a int 
exec dbo.TestProc @a output
select @a
```

[Check Demo here..](http://rextester.com/UZQV78702) Hope this helps!!!